# Reputation widget failure on Android

Tags: support, bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

The title says it all. When I try to place the reputation widget on my home screen, I get this:
[image: fail 1]
When I try again, I get this error, presumably because the Stack Exchange service has stopped.
[image: fail 2]
Is this a bug? If so, where should I report it?

I am running Android 5.1 armeabi on a DigiLand DL718M tablet.

Comment: Did you click the "Report" button on the dialog? That will send a bug report to the developer with the salient information.

Comment: I have [**exactly** the same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285619/reputation-widget-crash) on my Samsung Galaxy S4. I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: What's your StackExchange app version?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy 1.0.89, and according to Google Play, it's up to date.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the same version.

Comment: Same problem here on Lollipop (well, Viper 10 ROM) on an HTC 10. Widget from previous version of SE app works fine.

Comment: @Arulkumar You're right, thanks!