# Reputation widget crash

Tags: support, bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

I have an issue with crashing **reputation widget** when it's added to the home screen. When I add it for the first time, it says "*Please login before using this widget*" (even though the app itself is logged in already). So I open the app, go back to the home screen, add the widget again and it crashes (and it's not added to the home screen). When I'll try to add it again, it says "*Please login before using this widget*" again. And then it just repeats - "*Please login...*", execute the app, crash, "*Please login...*", etc.

Restart of the device didn't make any change.

I have found [another user with a different device and completely same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285261/reputation-widget-failure-on-android?rq=1).

**My set up**:

Stack Exchange app version: `1.0.89`
Android version: `5.0.1`
Device: Samsung Galaxy S4

Comment: Did you try to reboot of your device?

Comment: Yep, sure, sorry I didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: Also, I have found [another user with a different device and completely same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285261/reputation-widget-failure-on-android?rq=1).

Comment: Same problem here on Lollipop (well, Viper 10 ROM) on an HTC 10. Widget from previous version of SE app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the current app version. I could add the widget with an older version but it failed with the newest version, on the same device (tested with Nexus 5 Android 6.0, and Google Pixel Android 7.1).

So if you want a workaround:

1. Uninstall the Stack Exchange app.
2. Download an older version (e.g. [1.0.83 from APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-stack-exchange/stack-exchange-stack-exchange-1-0-83-release/stack-exchange-1-0-83-android-apk-download/)).
3. Open it and log in (Warning: Google sign-in might not work).
4. Add the reputation widget to your homescreen.
5. Go to the Play Store and update the app to the most recent version (if you want to).

---

Also, here is the stacktrace of the crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 21322
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stackexchange.marvin/com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.widget.ReputationWidgetConfigure}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.widget.ReputationWidgetConfigure.SiteSelectorFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.widget.ReputationWidgetConfigure.SiteSelectorFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:435)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:414)
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:138)
   at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.widget.ReputationWidgetConfigure.onCreate(ReputationWidgetConfigure.java:63)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```